# Set selected select option using HTML only

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

What's the property to select an option from a select element form bootstrap, only using HTML?
**Example:**

```
<select ?PROPERTY_DEFAULT_OPTION?=3>
   <option value="1">Blue</option>
   <option value="2">Yellow</option>
   <option value="3">Green</option>
   <option value="4">Brown</option>
</select>
```

What would be the property name to set the default selected option to value 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Blue</option>
    <option value="2">Yellow</option>
    <option value="3" selected>Green</option>
    <option value="4">Brown</option>
</select>
```

All you need to use is a `selected` property.

And it's not even bootstrap, it's pure HTML.